# Java Date.parse IllegalArgument

Tags: java, date

I'm writing a test for a method that invokes Date.parse(). The code looks like this

```
    public void someMethod(String s){

         Date date = new Date();

         date.setTime(Date.parse(s));

         //other methods
    }
```

in my test I did something like this

```
    public void test(){
          ...

          Date date = new Date();
          someMethod(date.toString());

          //assert statements
    }
```

It works well on my machine, I tried it in my eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA. However, when I push it to our server for build, the test fails. It throws IllegalArgumentException. My teammate receives the same exception also. We have are using the same sdk: jdk1.7.0 and IDE eclipse and IntelliJ. The only difference is I have a jre7 installed in my machine. I also tried a simple test:

```
    public void test(){
          Date d = new Date();
          String s = d.toString();

          Date e = new Date();
          e.setTime(Date.parse(s));

          sysout(e);
    }
```

Works well in my machine, but receives IllegalArgumentException in his machine. I cannot change the method under test so I cannot perform other conversion from string to date. Thanks

EDIT - StackTrace

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)
        at package.Class.Method(Class.java:135)
        at package.TestClass.TestMethod(TestMethod.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Sorry I cannot edit it properly, the javascript is disabled in my machine

Comment: Do you have the exact StackTrace of the error? What is the output of `d.toString()` on your machine vs on the other machine? Do you have different locales installed?

Comment: I forgot to tell that I'm not allowed to modify the code, so I'm going for the date's timestamp as parameter for test. I'll also suggest to our developers to update their codes if possible as some of the codes contain depricated methods since they are written quite some time ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.toString()` and `Date.parse()` are locale-dependent. As a result, it is possible for `toString()`'s output to not be unambiguously readable by `parse()`. It would be better to pass the date's timestamp, since that is just a number and is therefore unique.

Comment: On top of that, `Date.parse()` is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)) long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29) `Date.parse()` was deprecated as of JDK 1.1

So you would be better of changing the following code:

```
Date d = new Date();
String s = d.toString();

Date e = new Date();
e.setTime(Date.parse(s));
```

with something like this:

```
Date d = new Date();

Date e = new Date(); 
e.setTime(d.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not resolve your problem, i think having a look at the [DateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class would be very helpful for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse() is deprecated yet . 
Change the method as below and try it again .

```
public void someMethod(String s){
     Date date = new Date();
     try {
      date=DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(s);
     } catch (ParseException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
     }


     //other methods
}
```